# docker toolbox quick start fails with VBoxManage.exe error in Windows 10

Tags: virtualbox, docker-toolbox

I am trying to use docker in Windows 10 Home.

During install (in the Virtual Box part) I get an error:

> Cannot rename this connection. A connection with the name you
>   specified already exists. Specify a different name.

This can be closed and the installation continues.

However, when I click the quick start (`start.sh`) I get the following error:

> Starting "default"... (default) Check network to re-create if
>   needed... Unable to start the VM: C:\Program
>   Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe startvm default --type headless
>   failed: VBoxManage.exe: error: The virtual machine 'default' has
>   terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1). More
>   details may be available in
>   'C:\Users*****.docker\machine\machines\default\default\Logs\VBoxHardening.log
>   VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component
>   MachineWrap, interface IMachine Looks like something went wrong in
>   step ´Checking status on default´... Press any key to continue...

This error is already as an [Issue](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/473) for toolbox but the solutions that worked for some people didn't for me:

- Delete `.docker`  directory (in `C:\Users\<user.name>\.docker`);
- Reinstalling both virtualbox and docker toolbox;
- Check "Install VirtualBox with NDIS5 driver" during toolbox install.

Comment: Mine is also home edition, so I firstly download **DockerToolbox.exe** and install it right away, then I met the same situation as yours. This is how i solve it myself: 1) remove folder **C:\Users\<user.name>\.docker**  2)restart my pc.  I don't un-install virtualbox but it works fine though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to surpass this error with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33459377/4470542):

**Step 1**: Download and install https://www.virtualbox.org/attachment/ticket/14040/VBox-Win10-fix-14040.exe and leave it running in the background

**Step 2**: Head to the Virtual box program files (probably: `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox`).

**Step 3**: Go to compatibility for these three .exe ( Virtualbox.exe, VBoxHeadless.exe, and VBoxManage.exe ) and choose windows 7.

Run quick start and it works.

I'm not sure this was solely responsible for the solution because before this I also did:

- Delete `.docker`  directory (in `C:\Users\<user.name>\.docker`);
- Reinstalling both virtualbox and docker toolbox;
- Check "Install VirtualBox with NDIS5 driver" during toolbox install.

Answer (score 6):

Uninstall Virtual Box and reinstall using the following parameter in an Administrator command prompt:

**Note:** the latest VirtualBox version might be different:

`c:\downloads\VirtualBox-6.0.0-127566-Win.exe -msiparams NETWORKTYPE=NDIS5`

Comment: Thanks! That worked, no need for compatibility or other software working on the background.

Answer (score 4):

Try to run the quick start using an administrator. Specifically, right click the shortcut and choose 'Run as administrator'. This did the trick for me.

Comment: This worked for me (Docker Toolbox v19.03.1 and Windows 10 pro 64bits)

Answer (score 2):

I had to uninstall the VM virtual box. Installed the latest version. Ran Docker toolbox as an administrator and boom, it worked!

Comment: Worked for me. The first solution to try should be this.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers did not work for me. I uninstalled Docker Toolbox from Win10 Home. Also removed(all files too) the "default" VM created in Virtualbox.

On DockerToolbox-19.03.1.exe -> Right Click -> Troubleshoot compatibility. Ran compatibility check. Ran the installer in Adminstrator mode.

Then ran "Docker Quickstart Terminal" shortcut and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It simply means "Starting "default"... (default) Check network to re-create if needed... Unable to start the VM: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe startvm default --type headless "

[image]

which results in

[image]

and now solution is to check whether hypervisor is enabled if enabled swich it to off and restart host machine mentioned in :

[virtualbox Raw-mode is unavailable courtesy of Hyper-V windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50053255/virtualbox-raw-mode-is-unavailable-courtesy-of-hyper-v-windows-10)

### Heading